# Exit program on Spring jpa/Hibernate connection exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-jdbc

I want my program to exit if it cannot connect to the database on startup. Currently this connection is setup using the following:

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>${db.driver}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>${db.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>${db.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${db.password}</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.template" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${naming_strategy}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.check-valid-connection-sql">SELECT 1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.failOverReadOnly">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.maxReconnects">${maxreconnects}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.initialTimeout">${reconnect.interval}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Object, String> {

}
```

It's not obvious where I should place code to catch the runtime exceptions created by the connection failure. Are there any other settings I can use to exit if the database doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, spring will stop, if it could not create a bean at startup. If DB connection fails, then it will stop automatically anyway. Do you want to catch that exception, and do something before exit ?

Comment: Thanks, I just re-read and realised the servlet context had stopped, it was just the container that was still running. If you write yours as an answer, i'll give you the credit